# Solve: T(n) = T(n-1) + n

Tags: algorithm, math, recurrence

In Cormen's Introduction to Algorithm's book, I'm attempting to work the following problem:

**Show that the solution to the recurrence relation T(n) = T(n-1) + n  is O(n2 ) using substitution**

(There wasn't an initial condition given, this is the full text of the problem)

However, I can't seem to find out the correct process. The textbook only briefly touches on it, and most sites I've searched seem to assume I already know how. If someone could give me a simple, step by step guide, or even a link to one, I would appreciate it.

For kicks, here's my attempt so far:

**T(n) <= c(n^2) 

         <= c(n-1)^2 + n 

           <= c(n^2 -2n +1) + n (which I'm pretty sure is not < c(n^2))**

Thanks again.

UPDATE: Here's an example of the method I'm trying to accomplish, to avoid confusion.

**Prove the solution is O(nlog(n)) 

T(n) = 2T([n/2]) + n 

The substitution method requires us to prove that T(n) <= cn*lg(n) for a choice of constant c > 0. Assume this bound holds for all positive m < n, where m = [n/2], yielding T([n/2]) <= c[n/2]*lg([n/2]). Substituting this into the recurrence yields the following: 

T(n) <= 2(c[n/2]*lg([n/2])) + n 

        <= cn*lg(n/2) + n 

        = cn*lg(n) - cn*lg(2) + n 

        = cn*lg(n) - cn + n 

        <= cn*lg(n) 

where the last step holds as long as c >= 1** 
 
I can follow this logic just fine, but when I attempt to duplicate the steps in the problem above, I get stuck.

Comment: The homework tag is deprecated.

Comment: Can you add induction/substitution tag to this?  Its from the "substitution" segment of the book.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I guess this is supposed to be induction?

So base case n=1 is trivial.  Induction case, assume n>1.  (*) Suppose T(n-1) is O((n-1)<sup>2</sup>)=O(n<sup>2</sup>).  Show that T(n) is also O(n<sup>2</sup>).

```
 T(n) = T(n-1) + n
      < c (n-1)^2 + n,  assume c>1 wlog
      < c n^2 - 2cn + c + n
      < c n^2 - (2c - 1)n + c
      < c n^2
```

for n > 1, c > 1.

Here is the break out:

First, notice that when c > 1, 2c - 1 > c, so you have

```
      < c n^2 - (2c - 1)n + c
      < c n^2 - (c)n + c
```

Next, notice that when n > 1, -(c)n+c = (1-n) c < 0, so you have

```
      < c n^2 - (c)n + c
      < c n^2
```

Since there is a constant c such that T(n) < c n^2, clearly T(n) is O(n<sup>2</sup>).

Is that roughly along the line of what you want?  Had to edit it a bunch of times to fix edge cases.

Comment: I believe it is, how did you cancel into the last line, though? Your next to last line is as far as I could get.

Comment: basically, it's from the fact that n>1 and c>1.  added the explanation.  you're welcome :p

Comment: So, since 2c - 1 > c for c >1, you substitute c in for 2c - 1? Likewise for replacing (1-n)c with 0?

Comment: i didn't just randomly substitute.  By substituting, it makes the whole expression, namely *c n^2 - (2c - 1)n + c*, **larger**.  Why?  Because I've made a minus term, namely *- (2c - 1)n*, smaller by the substitution.  This lets me keep the < inequality.  This is because if A < B and I've created a C such that B < C, then I can conclude that A < C.  And likewise for (1-n)c and 0.

Comment: FYI: to be correct, all the < should be <=, but it just looks ugly and LaTeX symbols don't work.

Comment: Alright, I believe I understand now. You certainly explained yourself better than my textbook. Thank you very much!

Comment: No sweat.  Good luck with the class.

Comment: `to be correct, all the < should be <=` - what's wrong with ≤?

Answer (score 10):

Is that a pure math problem?

From T(n) = T(n-1) + n, we have:

```
T(n)   - T(n-1) = n
T(n-1) - T(n-2) = n-1
T(n-2) - T(n-3) = n-2
...
...
T(2)   - T(1)   = 2
T(1)   - T(0)   = 1
```

Summing all above equations gives us:

T(n) - T(0)    = 1 + 2 + ... + (n-1) + n = n * (n+1) / 2 = O(n ^ 2)

We're done.

**UPDATE** (I'm not sure if this is called substitution as the OP required):

```
T(n) = T(n-1) + n
= T(n-2) + (n-1) + n
= T(n-3) + (n-2) + (n-1) + n
= ... 
= T(1) + (2 + 3 + ... + n)
= T(0) + (1 + 2 + ... + n)
= T(0) +  n * (n+1) / 2
= O(n ^ 2)
```

Comment: That's appreciated, but I believe that is iteration, not substitution. That may come in handy on a later problem though, thanks

Comment: I updated my answer, is that what you need?

Comment: I believe substitution involves replacing T(N) with, in this case, c(n^2), and using that to prove the relation. Hence my vain attempt above. Your solution seems to involve a method later in the book, called either iteration or solving the recurrence tree. Again, I could be wrong. If I knew I was right, I wouldn't be here :)